# Android In App Purchase failing saying - "Invalid credit card number"

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase, google-play

I am using Cordova Purchase Plugin:
https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase#rb3.9

This plugin allows In-App Purchases to be made from Cordova and PhoneGap applications, on Android, iOS and Windows (Store/Phone 8.1).

I built my application in android and then tested the In-App Purchases in real device.

It asked me to enter the credit/debit card details but I am getting **"Invalid credit card number"** error after submit my debit card details.

I am using **Closed Alpha Testing** from Google Play.

Comment: i also facing the same issue..Did u get any hint on it?